# Check whether an input is real of integer

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to ask the user to input a variable and check it is real or integer and take two different operations for corresponding actions. Say true if integer else false;

fun realorinteger(n)= if n=int then true else false;

but it definitely does not work. I tried if n in int as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.

The type system simply doesn't allow a function to take multiple different types, and act according to which type it is. Either your function takes an `int`, or it takes a `real`. (Or it takes both, but can also take `string`s, `list`s, etc... ie. is polymorphic)

You could fake it by making a datatype, which encapsulates values that can be either integers or reals, like so:

```
datatype intorreal = IVal of int | RVal of real
```

You can then use pattern matching on such a value to extract the desired number:

```
fun realorinteger (IVal i) = ... (* integer case here *)
  | realorinteger (RVal r) = ... (* real case here *)
```

This function will then have the type `intorreal -> x`, where `x` is the type of the right-hand-side expressions. Note, the resulting value must be of the same type in both cases.

An example of such a function could be a rounding function:

```
fun round (IVal i) = i
  | round (RVal r) = Real.round r
```

Which is then called like so:

```
val roundedInt  = round (IVal 6);
val roundedReal = round (RVal 87.2);
```